# How to detach only the last record in the pivot table using detach() in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

If I do this:

`return $this->roles()->detach($role);`

all roles are removed.

How to limit that to only the last one?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without timestamps:

```
$lastRole = $user->roles()
    ->orderBy( $user->roles()->getTable() .'id', 'desc')
    ->first();
$user->roles()->detach($lastRole);
```

or with timestamps:

```
$lastRole = $user->roles()->latest()->first();
$user->roles()->detach($lastRole);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this, I did not test it:

`return $this->roles()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->detach($role);`

You can also order by timestamps, if no primary id is present, like this:

`return $this->roles()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->detach($role);`

for this to work, you also have to edit your model, from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables):

> If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained
>   created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the withTimestamps method on
>   the relationship definition:

`return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withTimestamps();`

Comment: Yes, that would be great, i.e. I have a column `created_at` as a timestamp and I would like to select the last one there (latest) and remove it. How to do that?

Comment: I edited the original post with infromation regarding timestamps in pivot tables.

Comment: I tried your code by I am getting this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()`

Comment: I already have withTimestamps() chaining for belongsToMany. But I am getting this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()`. It seems like `detach()` cannot be used to remove just one row, e.g. the latest. Or am I wrong and it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing would be not to use model at all, because looking at this [issue #3585](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3585) it is not that easy. Taylor closed it without a comment, so I assume it not get implemented. The solution should be (assuming you have timestamps columns migrated in the table). Tested code:

```
$last = DB::table($user->roles()->getTable())
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->first();
DB::table($user->roles()->getTable())
    ->where('created_at', '=', $last->created_at)
    ->delete();
```